# How to count height score from a table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
   SELECT * FROM `result` Where R_TestID=16 AND R_IsCorrect='yes'.
```

Actually I want this Where clasue and also count more repeated R_UserID.
Bundle of Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to count rows? SELECT count(*) FROM ...

Comment: Expected result will be more than helpful.

Comment: i want to count R_UserID and they give me 2 in a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct(R_UserID)) FROM `result` Where R_TestID=16 AND R_IsCorrect='yes'.
```

Comment: You are a genious:) I want this simplest query. do not mind @scais edge

Answer (score 2):

You can do this  group by, order desc  and limit 1

```
 select count(*) as my_val from `result`  Where R_TestID=16 AND R_IsCorrect='yes'
 group by R_UserID
 order by my_val desc 
 limit 1
```

Comment: `from Where`? missed the table name ;-)

Comment: `select count(*) as my_val from result Where R_TestID=16 AND R_IsCorrect='yes'` - not as per your edit ;-)

Comment: hehe there we go ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
  `R_UserID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `R_TestID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `R_IsCorrect` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `result` (`R_UserID`, `R_TestID`, `R_IsCorrect`) VALUES
(1, 16, 'yes'),
(1, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes'),
(2, 16, 'yes');


SELECT R_UserID, COUNT(*) AS user_count
FROM `result` 
WHERE R_TestID=16 AND R_IsCorrect='yes' 
GROUP BY R_UserID
ORDER BY user_count DESC;
```

output

```
R_UserID   user_count 
2          6
1          2
```

Comment: Yes This is also requried for me. here is all expert:)

Comment: you can do you will do everything in this world but when you try by heart :)